# Problem with Flutter app Google permissions and/or code signing

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I am having trouble getting Android permissions and/or Play Store code signing to work correctly with my Flutter app, which accesses Google Fit data.

**My configuration:**

I'm still just doing internal releases, so have not yet requested Google "verification" of my app.

I have two build flavors: flavor_alpha and flavor_dev, which connect to different Firebase databases.
For both flavors, the app attempts to access Google Fit data on the local device.

Each flavor has its own google-services.json, containing:

- valid Firebase project info (project number, id, etc.)
- "client_info" and "oauth_client" data which references the correct (I think!) client_id, package_name, certificate_hash.

For "local" testing, I build/install the app using a variety of mechanims. Behavior is the same for each:

- directly via VS Code
- flutter build apk; flutter install
- flutter build appbundle; bundletool build-apks; bundletool install-apks

For "Play Store" testing, I build using "flutter build appbundle" then drag/drop the appbundle onto the Play store release upload webpage.

**Behavior with flavor_alpha:**

Access to Firebase project id: mydb-alpha

- successfully authenticates via firebase_auth using email/password
- successfully accesses data in Cloud Firestore

Access to device's Google Fit data (via "fit_kit" package)

- ***successful*** access for locally installed build
- ***unsuccessful*** if downloaded via Google Play

I assume this difference is due to re-signing that Google Play does. I have read and re-read the documentation related to keys and code signing, and I have tried changing the keys in google_services.json, but have not managed to resolve the problem. There's some detail I'm missing or not understanding fully. Also, due to the permissions problems I have with the other flavor (see below), I am not 100% convinced it is due to re-signing.

**Behavior with flavor_dev:**

Access to Firebase project id: mydb-dev-123

- successfully authenticates via firebase_auth using email/password
- successfully accesses data in Cloud Firestore

Access to device's Google Fit data (via "fit_kit" package)

- ***fails*** to access in all cases (installed locally and via Play, debug and release)

**Suggestions?**

I don't understand why I am seeing different behavior for flavor_dev. Since it behaves differently from flavor_alpha, it seems I may have multiple things configured incorrectly in the build.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this, or at least help me confirm what is actually causing the problem(s)?